# getting started with pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

This might be a really stupid question but I'm not able to install pig properly on my machine.
Pig's version is 0.9.0.

I have even set my JAVA_HOME to its designated path .
I've set the PATH to

```
export PATH=/usr/local/pig-0.9.0/bin:$PATH
```

since my pig dir is in `/usr/local/`.
Whenever I type `pig` or `pig -help` I get the following message

```
su: /usr/local/pig-0.9.0/bin/pig: Permission denied
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is that file executable?

Comment: Yeah it is . I've been executing ant and hadoop in /usr/local directory .

Comment: That specific file (/usr/local/pig-0.9.0/bin/pig) must have the execute bit set for the appropriate user/group/world. Is that the case?

Comment: No because i tried logging in as root also but i got the same message : Permission denied . I just don't know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: If the file doesn't have the right execute bit set you can't run it, and root can't either.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks for letting me know . Can you please tell me how to set the right execute bit for specific users?

Comment: @Mat Thank you so much . I finally figured it out . I'm the biggest fool there is . Just had to chmod it .

Answer (score 1):

try to type:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/pig-0.9.0/bin/pig
```

Answer (score -1):

'chmod 777 -R /usr/local/pig-0.9.0/

usethis code definitely run

Comment: Mode `777` should never really be used. And in this case, directories in `/usr/` should belong to root with permissions `755`.